# PowerShell - How to format the output of two distinct commands in one table?

Tags: powershell

```
Foreach($a In Get-GPO -All) { Foreach($b In $a | Get-GPPermissions -TargetName "Domain Admins" -TargetType Group) { $a.DisplayName; $b.Trustee.Name; $b.Permission } }
```

I use the command to output all GPO permission for Domain admins group. And by default Get-GPPermissions result does not include GPO name field. So I combine Get-GPO and Get-GPPermissions result to output GPO Name, Group Name and Permission. I need to output below sample. How to design my code?

```
GPO Name                   Group Name        Permission
---------                  -----------       -------------
Default Domain Policy      Domain Users      GpoEditDeleteModifySecurity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe objects to `Select-Object` to quickly create a PSObject with desired members:

```
Get-GPO -All | %{ 
    $permissions = $_ | Get-GPPermissions -TargetName 'Domain Admins' -TargetType Group
    $_ | Select-Object   @{Name='GPO Name';Expression={$_.DisplayName}}, 
                         @{Name='Group Name';Expression={$permissions.Trustee.Name}},
                         @{Name='Permission';Expression={$permissions.Permission}}
}
```

To get closer to your original line, though, something like this might be more appropriate:

```
Foreach ($GPO in Get-GPO -All) { 
    Foreach ($permission in $gpo | Get-GPPermissions -TargetName 'Domain Admins' -TargetType Group) { 
        '' | Select-Object   @{Name='GPO Name';Expression={$gpo.DisplayName}}, 
                             @{Name='Group Name';Expression={$permission.Trustee.Name}},
                             @{Name='Permission';Expression={$permission.Permission}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking something like PSObject.

First, we create an empty array that will then hold the combined foreach data sets.

We then run the script block and picking up desired values. Putting them all into a hash table that will work as a property set for a PSObject.

At the each end of foreach cycle we put PSObject's output into $obj and then start all over again.

```
    $obj=@()
    Foreach($a In Get-GPO -All) 
    { Foreach($b In $a | Get-GPPermissions -TargetName "Domain Admins" -TargetType Group)
         { 
           $properties = @{ 'DisplayName'=$a.DisplayName;
                            'Trustee'=$b.Trustee.Name;
                            'Permission'=$b.Permission;
                          }
           $psobj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties
           $obj+=$psobj
         } 
    }
Write-Output $obj
```

Comment: It would be great if you expanded this answer with some detailed explanation of what you're doing (creating new objects that contain the desired properties).